# Will it be a security issue if I set the owner of "/var/www" to group "www-data"

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I'm a noob here. I would like to know whether I will have any issues if I change ownership of `/var/www` to `www-data`, and what is the significance of `www-data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*/var/www* traditionally holds the necessary files to serve a website using a HTTP server such as Apache. Apache is executed by the user *www-data*, so interactive elements of the website (e.g., PHP scripts) have write access to pretty much everything owned by *www-data*.

Owning */var/www* by *www-data* is undesirable by the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). There's usually no need for a PHP script able to modify itself or other parts of the website.

If, for some reason, *www-data* needs to be able to modify or create some files, you can grant write permissions to those specific files (for modification) or write and execution permissions to a folder (for file creation) by owning them.